# SwiftUI initialising the same random view multiple times but it should not change

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am developing a game, with a main view from which you launch different levels. Each level is **the same view**, but this view itself has some randomness (that is generated via a function call in the view init), but this randomness should not change throughout the game. So each level should be generated once, each level different from the others based on parameters passed to its init, and then should not update/refresh even if subviews in the level do refresh. I am not managing to do it.

One idea was to not set a seed, but then in some cases the level does update mid-game. So now I set a seed, but then all the subviews are initialised with the same seed.

How do I make it such that each instance of the level view is only created once, and then stays the same all the time even if it disappears and reopens, while at the same time being random or at least semi-random, as in, initialised with a seed such thats its reproducible?

Full code on github: https://github.com/charelF/ThroughTheJungle

Here is the app:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ThroughTheJungleApp: App {
  @State var checkState: CheckState = .enabled
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      TabView {
        JungleView()
          .tabItem {
            Label("Game", systemImage: "list.dash")
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This calls my main view:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct JungleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    JungleView()
      .previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
  }
}

enum LevelState {
    case done
    case current
    case locked
}

struct GameBoardView: View {
  let buttonCount = 30
  @State var currentLevel = 1
  //  @State var checkState: CheckState
  
  func getPos(_ index: Int) -> (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, cx: CGFloat, cy: CGFloat) {
    let angle = -180 + (300 / Double(buttonCount - 1) * Double(index - 1))
    let radians = angle * .pi / 180
    let radius = 350.0
    let centerX = 150
    let centerY = 150
    let x = radius * cos(radians) + Double(centerX)
    let y = radius * sin(radians) + Double(centerY)
    return (x:x, y:y, cx: CGFloat(centerX), cy: CGFloat(centerY))
  }
  
  func getState(_ index: Int) -> LevelState {
    if index == currentLevel {
      return .current
    } else if index < currentLevel {
      return .done
    } else {
      return .locked
    }
  }
  
  func getColor(_ state: LevelState) -> Color {
    switch state {
    case .current: return .green
    case .done: return .yellow
    case .locked: return .green.opacity(0.3)
    }
  }
  
  @State var checkState = CheckState.enabled
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      ZStack() {
        ForEach(1...buttonCount, id: \.self) { index in
          let pos = getPos(index)
          let state = getState(index)
          let color = getColor(state)
          NavigationLink(
            destination: destinationView(for: index),
            label: {
            Circle()
              .foregroundColor(color)
              .shadow(color: color, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
              .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
              .overlay(
                Text("\(index)")
                  .bold()
                  .font(.system(size: 25, design: .rounded))
                  .foregroundColor(Color.white)
              )
          })
//          .disabled(state != .current)
          .position(x: pos.x, y: pos.y)
          Text("Through the Jungle")
            .bold()
            .font(.system(size: 30, design: .rounded))
            .foregroundColor(.green)
          
        }
      }
      .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
      .onChange(of: checkState) { state in
        if state == .solved {
          currentLevel += 1
          checkState = .enabled
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
      private func destinationView(for level: Int) -> some View {
          switch level {
          case 1:
            return AnyView(NumberSequenceView(checkState: $checkState, seed: 1))
          case 2:
            return AnyView(NumberSequenceView(checkState: $checkState, seed: 2))
          default:
              return AnyView(EmptyView())
          }
      }
}



struct JungleView: View {
  var body: some View {
    GameBoardView()
  }
}
```

which calls the level view

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum Sign: CaseIterable {
  case plus, minus, times
  func op() -> (Int, Int) -> Int {
    switch self {
    case .plus: return {a, b in return a + b}
    case .minus: return {a, b in return a - b}
    case .times: return {a, b in return a * b}
    }
  }
}

struct NumberSequenceView: View {

  var original: [Int]
  var masked: [Int?]
  @State var guesses: [Int?]
  @Binding var checkState: CheckState
  var ns: NumberSequence
  let seed: Int
  
  init(checkState: Binding<CheckState>, seed: Int) {
//    var generator = RandomNumberGeneratorWithSeed(seed: 941)
    ns = NumberSequence(seed: seed)
    self.seed = seed
    print("initialised ns with seed: \(seed)")
    let sequence = ns.generateSequence()
    original = sequence.original
    masked = sequence.masked
    guesses = sequence.masked
    self._checkState = checkState
  }
  
  @State private var myValue: Int = 0
  
  func getGuess(_ guess: Int?) -> String {
    if let guess {
      return String(guess)
    } else {
      return ""
    }
  }
  
  func getColor(_ val: Int?) -> Color {
    if val == nil {
      return Color.green.opacity(0.3)
    } else {
      return Color.gray.opacity(0.3)
    }
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      HStack {
        ForEach(0..<ns.listLength, id: \.self) { index in
          let m = masked[index]
          Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(getColor(m))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            .overlay(
              Group {
                if let m {
                  Text(String(m))
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 30, design: .rounded))
                } else {
                  TextField("", text: Binding(
                    get: { getGuess(guesses[index]) },
                    set: {
                      guesses[index] = Int($0) ?? nil
                      if !guesses.contains(where: { $0 == nil }) && !(checkState == .disabledBecauseTimer) {
                        checkState = .enabled
                        print("enabled")
                      }
                    }
                  ))
                  .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                  .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                  .bold()
                  .font(.system(size: 30, design: .rounded))
                }
              }
            )
        }
      }
      
      Text(String(describing: original))
      Text(String(describing: guesses))
      Text(String(describing: checkState != .solved))
      Text(String(describing: self.seed))
      
      CheckView(cond: {original == guesses}, checkState: $checkState)
//        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(checkState != .solved)
    }
  }
}


struct xxx1 : View {
  @State var checkState = CheckState.enabled
    var body: some View {
      NumberSequenceView(
          checkState: $checkState,
          seed: 1
        )
    }
}

struct NumberSequenceView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    xxx1()
  }
}

struct RandomNumberGeneratorWithSeed: RandomNumberGenerator {
    init(seed: Int) {
        // Set the random seed
        srand48(seed)
    }
    
    func next() -> UInt64 {
        // drand48() returns a Double, transform to UInt64
        return withUnsafeBytes(of: drand48()) { bytes in
            bytes.load(as: UInt64.self)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some logic of the level view:

```swift
import Foundation

class NumberSequence {
  let hiddenNumbers = 1
  let listLength: Int = 10
  var generator: RandomNumberGeneratorWithSeed
  
  init(seed: Int) {
    generator = RandomNumberGeneratorWithSeed(seed: seed)
  }
  
  func generateSequence() -> (original: [Int], masked: [Int?]) {
    
    var original: [Int] = []
    
    while true {
      print("original.count != listLength", original.count != listLength)
      print("original.max() ?? 0 < 150", original.max() ?? 0 < 150)
      original = []
      let sign1 = Sign.allCases.randomElement(using: &generator)!
      let val1 = Int.random(in: 1..<2)
      //    let sign2 = Sign.allCases.randomElement()
      //    let val2 = Int.random(in: 1..<10)
      let startValue = Int.random(in: 1..<50, using: &generator)
      
      var newValue = startValue
      for _ in 0..<listLength {
        original.append(newValue)
        newValue = sign1.op()(newValue, val1)
      }
      if (original.max()! < 150) && (original.min()! > 0) {
        break
      }
    }
    
    var randomIndexes = Set<Int>()
    while randomIndexes.count < hiddenNumbers {
      randomIndexes.insert(Int.random(in: 0..<listLength, using: &generator))
    }
    var masked = [Int?]()
    for i in 0..<listLength {
      if randomIndexes.contains(i) {
        masked.append(nil)
      } else {
        masked.append(original[i])
      }
    }
    return (original: original, masked: masked)
  }
  
}
```

and the button view with the button to solve the level:

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum CheckState {
  case solved
  case enabled
//  case disabledBecauseInput
  case disabledBecauseTimer
}

struct CheckView: View {
  
  var condition: () -> Bool
  @State var isTimerRunning = false
  @State var remainingTime = 10
  @State var remainingGuesses = 2
  let totalGuesses = 2
  
  @Binding var checkState: CheckState
//  @Environment(\.checkState) var checkState//: CheckState
  
  init(cond: @escaping () -> Bool, checkState: Binding<CheckState>) {
//  init(cond: @escaping () -> Bool, checkState: CheckState) {
    condition = cond
    self._checkState = checkState
  }
  
  var buttonText: String {
    switch $checkState.wrappedValue {
    case .disabledBecauseTimer:
      return "⏳"
    case .solved:
      return "✅"
    default:
      return "Check: (\(remainingGuesses)/\(totalGuesses)) \(checkState)"
    }
  }
  
  func buttonAction() {
    print("clicked")
    print(condition())
    if remainingGuesses > 0 {
      if condition() {
        checkState = .solved
        print("solved")
      } else {
        remainingGuesses -= 1
        if remainingGuesses <= 0 {
          checkState = .disabledBecauseTimer
          startTimer()
        } else {
          checkState = .enabled
        }
      }
    } else {
      checkState = .disabledBecauseTimer
      startTimer()
    }
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Button(action: buttonAction) {
        Text(buttonText)
          .bold()
          .font(.system(size: 30, design: .rounded))
          .padding()
          
      }
      .buttonStyle(.bordered)
      .disabled(checkState != .enabled)
      
      .padding()
      .disabled(checkState == .disabledBecauseTimer)
      
      Text(checkState == .disabledBecauseTimer ? formattedTime(remainingTime) : "")
        .bold()
        .font(.system(size: 30, design: .rounded))
        .padding()
    }
  }
  private func startTimer() {
    isTimerRunning = true
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
      if remainingTime > 0 {
        remainingTime -= 1
      } else {
        timer.invalidate()
        checkState = .enabled
        remainingGuesses = 1
        remainingTime = 10
      }
    }
  }
}
  
  private func formattedTime(_ seconds: Int) -> String {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
    formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad

    if let formattedString = formatter.string(from: TimeInterval(seconds)) {
        return formattedString
    }
    return ""
}

struct CheckViewPreviewContainer : View {
  @State var checkState = CheckState.enabled
    var body: some View {
        CheckView(
          cond: {false},
          checkState: $checkState
        )
    }
}

struct CheckView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  @State var checkState = CheckState.enabled
    static var previews: some View {
      CheckViewPreviewContainer()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have a model object that holds an array of levels and a current level property.  You can then pass the appropriate `Level` object to your views.  You might want to work through some SwiftUI tutorials.  Right now you have a lot of logic in your views that shouldn't be there.  Views are lightweight visual representations. Logic and state belongs in a model.

Comment: Thanks for the input, this is coincidentally the same thing GPT4 suggested, altough its proposed solution did not work. Out of interest, can you recomend anye any tutorials in particular that address design patterns on how to store logic and state in swiftUI?

Comment: Apple has some good ones https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui and there is https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui